# How to compare range of integer values in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, compare, between

I am trying to compare a range of integer values between a test table and a reference table. If any range of values from the test table overlaps with the available ranges in the reference table, it should be deleted.

Sorry if it's not clear but here is an example data:

**TEST_TABLE:**

```
MIN          MAX
10           121
122          648
1200         1599
```

**REFERENCE_TABLE:**

```
MIN          MAX
50           106
200          1400
1450         1500
```

**MODIFIED TEST_TABLE:** (expected result after running PL/SQL)

```
MIN          MAX
10           49
107          121
122          199
1401        1449
1501        1599
```

In the first row from the example above, the 10-121 has been cut down into two rows: 10-49 and 107-121 because the values 50, 51, ..., 106 are included in the first row of the reference_table (50-106); and so on..

Here's what I've written so far with nested loops. I've created two additional temp tables that would store all the values that would be found in the reference table. Then it would create new sets of ranges to be inserted to test_table.

But this does not seem to work correctly *and* might cause performance issues especially if we're dealing with values of millions and above:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (num_value NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE new_table_next (num_value NUMBER, next_value NUMBER);
```

-- PL/SQL start

```
DECLARE
  l_count NUMBER;
  l_now_min NUMBER;
  l_now_max NUMBER;

  l_final_min NUMBER;
  l_final_max NUMBER;

BEGIN

  FOR now IN (SELECT min_num, max_num FROM test_table) LOOP
    l_now_min:=now.min_num;
    l_now_max:=now.max_num;
    WHILE (l_now_min < l_now_max) LOOP

      SELECT COUNT(*) -- to check if number is found in reference table
      INTO l_count
      FROM reference_table refr
      WHERE l_now_min  >= refr.min_num
      AND l_now_min   <= refr.max_num;

      IF l_count        > 0 THEN

        INSERT INTO new_table (num_value) VALUES (l_now_min);
        COMMIT;

      END IF;

      l_now_min:=l_now_min+1;

    END LOOP;

    INSERT INTO new_table_next (num_value, next_value)
    VALUES (SELECT num_value, (SELECT MIN (num_value) FROM new_table t2 WHERE t2.num_value > t.num_value) AS next_value FROM new_table t);

    DELETE FROM test_table t
    WHERE now.min_num   = t.min_num
    AND now.max_num   = t.max_num;
    COMMIT;

    SELECT (num_value + 1) INTO l_final_min FROM new_table_next;
    SELECT (next_value - num_value - 2) INTO l_final_max FROM new_table_next;

    INSERT INTO test_table (min_num, max_num)
        VALUES (l_final_min, l_final_max);
    COMMIT;

    DELETE FROM new_table;
    DELETE FROM new_table_next;

    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Please help, I'm stuck. :)

Comment: Do you really need this done in PL/SQL? Why? Will a straight SQL query not work? Then: What is your Oracle version? Different solutions (using different features of the language) are possible depending on version. Lastly, are the ranges in the REFERENCE_TABLE already pre-processed so that you can guarantee the table does not include overlapping ranges? If not, the problem can still be solved, but it would be easier if the ranges are known to be non-overlapping.

Comment: I can’t think of a way on how to handle this with a straight SQL query. Also, yes. The reference_table is known to have no overlapping values.

Comment: And your Oracle version is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind this approach is to unwind both tables, keeping track of whether the numbers are in the reference table or the original table.  This is really cumbersome, because adjacent values can cause problems.

The idea is then to do a "gaps-and-islands" type solution along both dimensions -- and then only keep the values that are in the original table and not in the second.  Perhaps this could be called "exclusionary gaps-and-islands".

Here is a working version:

```
with vals as (
      select min as x, 1 as inc, 0 as is_ref
      from test_table
      union all
      select max + 1, -1 as inc, 0 as is_ref
      from test_table
      union all
      select min as x, 0, 1 as is_ref
      from reference_table
      union all
      select max + 1 as x, 0, -1 as is_ref
      from reference_table
     )
select min, max
from (select refgrp, incgrp, ref, inc2, min(x) as min, (lead(min(x), 1, max(x) + 1) over (order by min(x))  - 1) as max
      from (select v.*,
                  row_number() over (order by x) - row_number() over (partition by ref order by x) as refgrp,
                  row_number() over (order by x) - row_number() over (partition by inc2 order by x) as incgrp
            from (select v.*, sum(is_ref) over (order by x, inc) as ref,
                         sum(inc) over (order by x, inc) as inc2
                  from vals v
                 ) v
           ) v
      group by refgrp, incgrp, ref, inc2
     ) v
where ref = 0 and inc2 = 1 and min < max
order by min;
```

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=347cc263d92a8bb4ab0ba4da11668a71) is a db<>fiddle.

The inverse problem of getting the overlaps is much easier.  It might be feasible to "invert" the reference table to handle this.

```
select greatest(tt.min, rt.min), least(tt.max, rt.max)
from test_table tt join
     reference_table rt
     on tt.min < rt.max and tt.max > rt.min  -- is there an overlap?
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But from your db fiddle, the third row has a min value of 122 and max value of 121?

Comment: @KAYLE . . . Yes, you have to add the additional condition `min < max`, to handle "adjacencies".  I must've removed that from the fiddle.

Comment: If you don't want to use `UNPIVOT` that's OK, but the efficient way to unpivot without using the `UNPIVOT` operator is not a `UNION ALL` (which requires reading the table twice); rather, it is a cross join to a table with two rows, which you can create in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is modified from a similar task (using dates instead of numbers) I did on Teradata, it's based on the same base data as Gordon's (all begin/end values combined in a single list), but uses a simpler logic:

```
WITH minmax AS 
 ( -- create a list of all existing start/end values (possible to simplify using Unpivot or Cross Apply)
   SELECT Min AS val, -1 AS prio, 1 AS flag  -- main table, range start
   FROM test_table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Max+1,   -1, -1                      -- main table, range end
   FROM test_table
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT Min, 1,  1                      -- reference table, adjusted range start
   FROM reference_table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Max+1, 1, -1                      -- reference table, adjusted range end
   FROM reference_table
 )
, all_ranges AS 
 ( -- create all ranges from current to next row
   SELECT minmax.*,
     Lead(val) Over (ORDER BY val, prio desc, flag) AS next_val,  -- next value = end of range
     Sum(flag) Over (ORDER BY val, prio desc, flag ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS Cnt -- how many overlapping periods exist
   FROM minmax
 )
SELECT val, next_val-1
FROM all_ranges
WHERE Cnt = 1           -- 1st level only
  AND prio + flag =  0  -- either (prio -1 and flag  1) = range start in base table
                        --     or (prio  1 and flag -1) = range end in ref table
ORDER BY 1
```

See [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3be634c5791a643e5f42735f1b92f9d9)

Comment: Could you explain the meaning behind labeling the main table min as -1,1 etc? What are those flags and prio columns for?

Comment: @KAYLE The `flag` is for counting the number of overlapping ranges using a Cumulative Sum over `+1` when the range starts and `-1` when it ends (Gordon named it `inc` in his solution). The `prio` (Gordon's `is_ref`) is used to tag the table where the row is coming from, might be any value `1/0`,  `a/b`, `foo/bar`. I'm using +/-1 because it simplifies the Where-condition to `prio + flag = 0` instead of `((prio = -1 and flag = 1) or (prio = 1 and flag = -1))`

Comment: I tried to interchange the values of the reference table and test table and the output seems to be not correct. It created a row with Min 122 Max 200; when the values within this range does not exist in the original main table in the first place. See [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=833944f9dea04616c86bf63fb5e8e135)

Comment: @KAYLE: It's a +/- 1 problem, should be fixed now

Comment: If you don't want to use `UNPIVOT` that's OK, but the efficient way to unpivot without using the `UNPIVOT` operator is not a `UNION ALL` (which requires reading the table twice); rather, it is a cross join to a table with two rows, which you can create in the query itself.

Comment: @mathguy: Well, it's not that I don't want to use `unpivot`, but Oracle isn't my main DBMS and I'm not familiar with the exact syntax (don't know how to get `flag/prio`). But assume that `cross apply` is better than a `cross join` (again not familiar with the former syntax)

Comment: In this case, a cross join would be fine - there is no "grouping by rows" that you need to preserve. Also, cross join to `select -1 from dual union all select +1 from dual` is (close to) SQL Standard, it should work in any RDBMS (other than `dual` of course).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this. I put the test data in a WITH clause rather than creating the tables (I find this is easier for testing purposes). I used your column names (MIN and MAX); these are very poor choices though, as MIN and MAX are Oracle keywords. They will generate confusion for sure, and they may cause queries to error out.

The strategy is simple - first take the COMPLEMENT of the ranges in REFERENCE_TABLE, which will also be a union of intervals (using NULL as marker for minus infinity and plus infinity); then take the intersection of each interval in TEST_TABLE with each interval in the complement of REFERENCE_TABLE. How that is done is shown in the final (outer) query in the solution below.

```
with
  test_table (min, max) as (
    select   10,  121 from dual union all
    select  122,  648 from dual union all
    select 1200, 1599 from dual
  )
, reference_table (min, max) as (
    select   50,  106 from dual union all
    select  200, 1400 from dual union all
    select 1450, 1500 from dual
  )
, 
  prep (min, max) as (
    select lag(max) over (order by max) + 1 as min
         , min - 1                          as max
      from ( select min, max   from reference_table
             union  all
             select null, null from dual
           )
  )
select   greatest(t.min, nvl(p.min, t.min)) as min
     ,   least   (t.max, nvl(p.max, t.max)) as max
from     test_table t inner join prep p
                      on  t.min <= nvl(p.max, t.max)
                      and t.max >= nvl(p.min, t.min)
order by min
;

       MIN        MAX
---------- ----------
        10         49
       107        121
       122        199
      1401       1449
      1501       1599
```

Comment: Can you compare this and my query against a larger dataset? I would like to know about performance on Oracle (I usually try to avoid non-equi-joins because they tend to be quite inefficient for a large number of rows in a parallel system like Teradata)

Comment: @dnoeth - the comparison may also depend on the existence of indexes (for example, an index on `min` in `test_table`). In most cases, though, I believe a query like you (and Gordon) wrote, unpivoting everything, should be more efficient. It probably also depends on the sizes of both tables; if one of them is only a few rows, vs. the tables both being millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Example to resolve the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE xrange_reception
(
    vdeb    NUMBER,
    vfin    NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE xrange_transfert
(
    vdeb    NUMBER,
    vfin    NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE xrange_resultat
(
    vdeb    NUMBER,
    vfin    NUMBER
);

insert into xrange_reception values (10,50);

insert into  xrange_transfert values (15,25);
insert into  xrange_transfert values (30,33);
insert into  xrange_transfert values (40,45);

DECLARE
    CURSOR cr_rec IS SELECT * FROM xrange_reception;

    CURSOR cr_tra IS
          SELECT *
            FROM xrange_transfert
        ORDER BY vdeb;

    i              NUMBER;
    vdebSui        NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR rc IN cr_rec
    LOOP
        i := 1;
        vdebSui := NULL;

        FOR tr IN cr_tra
        LOOP
             IF tr.vdeb BETWEEN rc.vdeb AND rc.vfin
            THEN
                IF i = 1 AND tr.vdeb > rc.vdeb
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO xrange_resultat (vdeb, vfin)
                         VALUES (rc.vdeb, tr.vdeb - 1);
                ELSIF i = cr_rec%ROWCOUNT AND tr.vfin < rc.vfin
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO xrange_resultat (vdeb, vfin)
                         VALUES (tr.vfin, rc.vfin);
                ELSIF vdebSui < tr.vdeb
                THEN
                    INSERT INTO xrange_resultat (vdeb, vfin)
                         VALUES (vdebSui + 1, tr.vdeb - 1);
                END IF;

                vdebSui := tr.vfin;
                i := i + 1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        IF vdebSui IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF vdebSui < rc.vfin 
            THEN
                INSERT INTO xrange_resultat (vdeb, vfin)
                     VALUES (vdebSui + 1, rc.vfin);
            END IF;

        ELSE
            INSERT INTO xrange_resultat (vdeb, vfin)
                 VALUES (rc.vdeb, rc.vfin);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

So:

Table xrange_reception:

```
vdeb  vfin
10    50
```

Table xrange_transfert:

```
vdeb  vfin
15    25
30    33
40    45
```

Table xrange_resultat:

```
vdeb  vfin
10    14
26    29
34    39
46    50
```